# How to bulk insert in peewee python?

Tags: postgresql, flask, peewee

I'm trying to bulk insert data from a form table into python database which have a foreign key using peewee. I followed this guide [Bulk insert with foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48599465/bulk-inserting-on-table-with-foreign-key-field) and I manage to insert it:

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Sz6E.png)

However, that's not the value that I type. This is my code for passing the form table:

```
# services
    headers = ('types','descriptions', 'rates', 'hours', 'actuals')
    values = (
                req2('quote_service_type[]'),
                req2('quote_service_description[]'),
                req2('quote_service_rates[]'),
                req2('quote_service_hours[]'),
                req2('quote_service_actual_amount[]')
    )

    services = [ {} for i in range(len(values[0])) ]
    for x, i in enumerate(values):
        for _x,_i in enumerate(i):
            services[_x][headers[x]] = _i

    jsonify(services)
```

An this is a modified code for inserting the data in the database which I followed:

```
 data = {name : (services)}

    client_to_id = {}

for name in data:
            if name not in client_to_id:
                new_clients = QuoteClient.create(client_id=client_id, name=name, company=company, project=project, telephone=telephone, email=email, 
                                            address=address, quote=quote, tax_rate=tax_rate, subtotal=subtotal, tax_amt=tax_amount ,date=date, pdf_file=pdf, due=due, total=total)
                client_to_id[name] = new_clients.client_id

for name, services in data.items():
            client = client_to_id[name]
            service = [{'client_id': client, 'types': types, 'descriptions': descriptions, 'rates': rates, 'hours': hours, 'actuals':actuals} for types, descriptions, rates, hours, actuals in services]
            QuoteServices.insert_many(service).execute()
```

Also the models:

```
class QuoteClient(BaseModel):
  client_id = pw.PrimaryKeyField(default='')
  name = pw.CharField(unique=True)
  company = pw.CharField(default='')
  telephone = pw.CharField(default='')
  email = pw.CharField(unique=True)
  address = pw.TextField(default='')
  project = pw.TextField(default='')
  quote = pw.CharField(unique=True)
  tax_rate = pw.CharField(default='')
  tax_amt = pw.CharField(default='')
  subtotal = pw.CharField(default='')
  date = pw.DateField( formats='%m-%d-%Y')
  due = pw.DateField(formats='%m-%d-%Y')
  total = pw.FloatField(default='')
  pdf_file = pw.BlobField(default='')

class QuoteServices(BaseModel):
  client_id = pw.ForeignKeyField(QuoteClient, backref='services')
  types = pw.CharField(default='')
  descriptions = pw.CharField(default='')
  rates = pw.CharField(default='')
  hours = pw.CharField(default='')
  actuals = pw.CharField(default='')
```

Why did the values not inserted properly into the database?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me - at least I don't see any obvious problem. You might step through or enable logging to see if the expected queries are being executed?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the reason. Apparently I have to pass the values like this since it's in a dictionary:

```
service = [{'client_id': client, 'types': values['types'], 'descriptions': values['descriptions'], 'rates': values['rates'], 'hours': values['hours'], 'actuals': values['actuals']} for values in services]
```